# VBA Macro to loop through all options, copy+paste rows into different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a template sheet that will act as a summary for individual projects in my portfolio (I have 3 unique projects). I would like this template auto-populate based on VBA macro for each desired field.

This template is on a sheet called `RegionSummary`.

To start, I would select in `RegionSummary` cell `R6` which is a named-range dropdown list. I would select one of three projects.

Here is a link to a screengrab of this template:

[image]

From there, I would click a macro-button that will filter cells `A6:A553` in my data sheet called "Regions" based on the criteria in `RegionSummary!R6` (my reference project-name cell).

{I have the macro written for this step already}

Next, (and this is where I require help) I need a macro that would be activated by a macro-button that will go through all of the unique filter options for `Regions!B6:B553` (header is `B5`) one by one, and copy `Regions!A3:R3`, and paste that data into `RegionSummary!A12:R12`. There should be as many unique rows in `RegionSummary` as there are unique values that would be filtered in `Regions!B6:B553`.

Here is a link to a screengrab of the data sheet:

[image]

```
{Cells Regions!A3:R3 are formulas that are pulling specific information from the main data set in Regions!B6:B553}
```

This is what the final result should look like:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to do this in VBA? Thank you for any help in advance.